# Collection accessed from mongosh doesn't see collection imported with mongo compass

Tags: mongodb

I opened MongoDB Compass, created the "Esercitazione" database, created a "Restaurants" collection inside of it and imported data into this collection. I am able to query this collection through the MongoDB Compass tools.

[image]

Problem is that when I try to access it through the Mongo Shell I get an empty collection...

[image]

Comment: The database names are different in both the screenshots, first ss `Esercitazioni`, and second ss `Esercitazione`

Comment: You got me! Weird though that it doesn't give any error / warning

Comment: In mongosh, when you `use any_db_name` it doesn't give any warning/error if the database doesn't exist. Its a characteristic of MongoDB that you can use a database and insert in a collection without explicitly creating them.

Answer (score 0):

thanks this was the issue for me too -
The database names are different in both the screenshots, first ss Esercitazioni, and second ss Esercitazione –
turivishal

I wish it gives error message when collection is not there.

thx Prasad for clarifying why there is no error!